# Sed to replace content across multiple lines delimited by braces

Tags: regex, sed

I'm looking for a sed function that would be able to do find a set of lines and replace it with another set using delimiters.

Example

**Source:**

```
class Requests
{
  function approveRequests($users){
    foreach($users as $user){
      if(hasQualified($user)){
         acceptUser($user);
      }else{
         rejectUser($user)
      }
   }
 }
```

}

**To**:

```
class Requests
{
  function approveRequests($users){
    autoAcceptMember($users);
  } 
}
```

Please note the the source might have several sets of other braces but they will be equally matched. so it there are 3 opening, then there will be 3 closing and so I'd like to get everything in-between

Comment: Prefix your code with four whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is not able to do the above it operates on a single lines only.

(OK, it can operate on multiple lines, but it can't distinguish between `}` that look the same).

You will have to use e.g. `awk` or other more advanced language (python, perl, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This will probably give an idea on how to edit your file with sed.

```
cat inputFile.txt | sed -n '/^class Requests/,/^}/ p' | sed -e '/foreach/,$ d' | sed -e 's/\(function.*\)/\1\n    autoAcceptMember($users);\n  }\n}\n/'
```

**Output:**

```
class Requests
{
  function approveRequests($users){
    autoAcceptMember($users);
  }
}
```

**inputFile.txt:**

```
class here
{
    are
    some extra lines
} 

class Requests
{
  function approveRequests($users){
    foreach($users as $user){
      if(hasQualified($user)){
         acceptUser($user);
      }else{
         rejectUser($user)
      }
   }
 } 

}

class here2 {
    function are ()  {
        some extra lines 
        also
}
```

**Use sed and match with regex and print the lines between**

```
> cat inputFile.txt | sed -n '/^class Requests/,/^}/ p'
class Requests
{
  function approveRequests($users){
    foreach($users as $user){
      if(hasQualified($user)){
         acceptUser($user);
      }else{
         rejectUser($user)
      }
   }
 }

}
```

**Use sed and match with regex and delete the lines between**

```
sed -e '/foreach/,$ d' will give the following, in context:
> cat inputFile.txt | sed -n '/^class Requests/,/^}/ p' | sed -e '/foreach/,$ d'
class Requests
{
  function approveRequests($users){
```

**Use sed and match with regex, substitute and add tagged match**

```
sed -e 's/\(function.*\)/\1\n    autoAcceptMember($users);\n  }\n}\n/' will give the following, in context:
> cat inputFile.txt | sed -n '/^class Requests/,/^}/ p' | sed -e '/foreach/,$ d' | sed -e 's/\(function.*\)/\1\n    autoAcceptMember($users);\n  }\n}\n/'
class Requests
{
  function approveRequests($users){
    autoAcceptMember($users);
  }
}
```